# Manage zip from http get response

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have this problem:

I need to download a zip file from a server, this zip contains .xod and .png.
I'm using Angular js, java spring, to overcome the cross domain problem, my htt.get angular call java spring controller and it make a true get call.
I have to download zip -> return this zip to angular, unzip it, extract file and save it inside IndexedDB.

this is my angular code:

```
var req = {
             method: 'GET',
             url: CONTEXT_PATH+"/services/data/"+meetingId,
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': undefined
             }
    }

    $http(req).then(function(data){
        console.log("rest call done!");
        console.log(data);
    });
```

this is java spring code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/data/{meetingId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Buffer getMeeting(@PathVariable(value="meetingId") String meetingId) {
    byte[] file = new byte[2048];
    Buffer buf =null;
    try {

        String url = getContentServer()+"/data?username="+getUsername()+"&password="+getPassword()+"&id="+meetingId;

        logger.info("start Rest template");
        RestTemplate templ = new RestTemplate();
        file = templ.getForObject(url, byte[].class);
        logger.info("PRE BUF");
        buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(file);
        logger.info("POST BUF");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = "Error retrieving meeting list";
        logger.error(msg, e);
    }
    logger.info("file zip  --> "+file.length);
    logger.info("buf --> "+buf+" -- buf.array --> "+ buf.array());
    return buf;
}
```

this is console.log:

> Object {data: "UEsDBBQACAAIAA5IpkgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJAAAAMTYwMzQucG…AcqwpAGxvZ28ucG5nUEsFBgAAAAAIAAgAuwEAAMa/KQAAAA==", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

I don't know I can decode this buffer and extract files inside it client side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a little to try to find a solution. My doubt is: The data you save in the dataBase is blob type or it's ok if you just save the path of the file?

Because I think is better to do that in server side. I love work in server side and the less I can in client. So searching for a java class which controls zip files I found this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html

And I wrote (without testing so it might be modified a little) this code server side:

```
Enumeration<E> listEntries = zip.entries()

  for (listEntries; listEntries.hasMoreElements();) {
    ZipEntry item = getEntry(listEntries.nextElement().toString())
    InputStream fileStream = getInputStream(item)
  }
```

With that InputStream you can return the list of the name of the files uncompressed or a hashmap, arraylist or just list of the streams and/or its fileName or whatever you need.

```
List<String> fileNames
```

or

```
HashMap<String, Object> filesStreams
```

for example.

Just I'm not very familiar with spring. It is posible to return a List or you have to return a Buffer? If you have to return a buffer tell me and I'll find another solution. ;)

Comment: First of all Thanks :). Pratically I have to pass this file to pdftron webviewer (angular side) to can read it and I'm searching for something that can do it, save this file insiede indexedDb is an idea, but actually not  solution. I return a Buffer becouse I had problem to return result from spring to angular. I need to pass this zip to angular and extract it client side, but I can't able to it actually. I am desperate

Comment: I have just read about webviewer and what you need is the path to instanziate it: 

http://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/doc/symbols/PDFTron.WebViewer.html#constructor[link]

But my question was if you can return a List<Buffer> instead of Buffer in that spring function, so you can identify each buffer with each file instead only one buffer. If what you need is the buffer of each file instead of urls.

Comment: Yes I can return it, I can decide what method have to return.

Comment: Well if your question was how to put the bytes into a file you should add **responseType: 'arraybuffer'** to your get request. So when data is returned you will have:

`var arrayBuffer = data.data; 
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
      // do something with each byte in the array
    }
  }`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data[link]

I though your problem was that you wanted a stream for each file in the zip instead the zip stream

Comment: Thanks, I'll try soon, instead java side is correct? return a Buffer whit a response type arraybuffer, as I done above?

Comment: responseType is specified in javascript side. If you go to the link you can see more information. The code I wrote (in the little coment) go inside $http(req) response in javascript side. 

If you want to get the zip file just left server side in that way. If you would prefer the content inside zip instead, you should modified server side to return a list of buffers of each file inside zip (like in my first big comment).

Comment: Now my console.log is this: Object {data: ArrayBuffer, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
config
:
Object
data
:
ArrayBuffer
byteLength
:
(...)
__proto__
:
ArrayBuffer
headers
:
(d)
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: link is dead, 404. Can I read buffer and convert every elements to blob to save it inside indexedDB? I don't understand if arraybuffer contains every files inside zip or what

Comment: If you want each file you should return a list of buffer with each file buffer from spring as I wrote in the first example.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what link was dead. Just delete the '[link]' at the end of the url. I though I had to write it as mini-Markdown says... Sorry :(